# Configuration of Cycles fisheye camera

Tags: cycles-render-engine, animation, camera

I try to use the cycles fisheye lens:

- with a `2/3"` sensor type
- camera is attached in the ceiling at `2.5m` in a room
- focal length is `2.2mm`
- filed of view is `180 degrees`.
- sensor size (2/3") is `8.8mm` * `6.6mm`.

However, when I chose a large sensor, the image plane of a camera is contracted and when I chose small sensor, the image plane of a camera is extended (image2). Normally, this means that like the focal distance is changed. But, I am not sure what exactly mean because when the focal changes, the field of view changes! Any explanation will be appreciated.

[image: image1]

[image: image2]

Comment: The *Sensor* represents how large of a detection device you have in the camera (in real life a [**Charge-Coupled Device**](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Charge-coupled_device)), no other parameters are affected.

Comment: @NoviceInDisguise, Sorry but I do not understand what do you mean?

Comment: Check [**this thread on BlenderArtists**](http://blenderartists.org/forum/showthread.php?251070-Camera-sensor-size-and-rendering). The *Image Sensor* option really is only to be used for motion tracking.

Comment: @NoviceInDisguise,   No, But when we change the size sensor we generate a zoom + or - if we use a fixed resolution image.

Answer (score 1):

The angle of coverage of a lens is determined by the size of the sensor and the focal length.

Blender is designed to deal with variation of all of these parameters as they would happen in real life in a real camera.

When you change the sensor size, the **Angle of Coverage** of a lens will be affected.

As an example. A 35mm lens in a full sensor 35mm camera with a sensor that is 36mm wide would be considered a "normal" lens (close to that of the human vision) with an angle of coverage of 54.432 degrees.

The same 50mm lens on a sensor that is 8.8mm Horizontally would be a very long telephoto with a field of view of barely 14.331 degrees.

The same lens on a large form at camera with a sensor with of 6.5cm would be a wide angle lens with a field of view of 89 degrees

[image]

Comment: Your example is not clear "As an example. A 35mm lens in a full sensor 35mm camera with a sensor that is 36mm wide would cover a field of view of 54.432 degrees."